# Can't copy table data

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm trying to copy my table (it hasn't any constrains, just `INT` primary key with autoincrement). I have written a method like below:

```
public void copyTable(String srcTableName, String dstTableName,
                      String[] srcColumns, String[] dstColumns) {
    String srcColumnsStr = TextUtils.join(", ", srcColumns);
    String dstColumnsStr = TextUtils.join(", ", dstColumns);
    String sql = String.format("INSERT INTO %s (%s) SELECT %s FROM %s",
            dstTableName, dstColumnsStr, srcColumnsStr, srcTableName);

    db.execSQL(sql);
}
```

In debugger I gonna the next sql-request:

```
INSERT INTO timetables (auto_complete, break_duration, color, first_lesson_time, first_week_date, id, lesson_duration, symbol, title, weeks) SELECT _auto_complete, _break_duration, _color, _first_lesson_time, _first_week_date, _id, _lesson_duration, _symbol, _title, _weeks FROM tmptimetables
```

In this table I had one row but after this request the row wasn't copied into a new table. Whaz wrong?

**TABLES**

```
CREATE TABLE tmptimetables (_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,_title NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,_weeks INTEGER NOT NULL,_first_week_date INTEGER NOT NULL,_auto_complete INTEGER NOT NULL,_first_lesson_time INTEGER NOT NULL,_lesson_duration INTEGER NOT NULL,_break_duration INTEGER NOT NULL,_color INTEGER NOT NULL,_symbol NCHAR(1) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE timetables (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,title NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,weeks INTEGER NOT NULL,first_week_date INTEGER NOT NULL,auto_complete INTEGER NOT NULL,first_lesson_time INTEGER NOT NULL,lesson_duration INTEGER NOT NULL,break_duration INTEGER NOT NULL,color INTEGER NOT NULL,symbol NCHAR(1) NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your tables do have constraints. `NOT NULL` is a constraint. It equates to do not insert into this table if this column is NULL. However, I don't believe this is the issue.

> A **NOT NULL constraint** *(highlight added)* may only be attached to a column definition, not
>   specified as a table constraint. Not surprisingly, a NOT NULL
>   constraint dictates that the associated column may not contain a NULL
>   value. Attempting to set the column value to NULL when inserting a new
>   row or updating an existing one causes a constraint violation.
>   [CREATE TABLE - SQL Data Constraints](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)

Rather, the problem may be; as per :-

> In this table I had one row but after this request the row wasn't
>   copied into a new table. Whaz wrong?

that you are trying to copy (INSERT from) the **tmptimetables** table into the **timetables** table. **tmptimetables**  whilst it might be that you actually want to copy from the timetables table into tmptimetables (if not then the liklihood is that the timetables table already has a row with the id that you are trying to insert.)

If so then instead of :-

```
String sql = String.format("INSERT INTO %s (%s) SELECT %s FROM %s",
        dstTableName, dstColumnsStr, srcColumnsStr, srcTableName);
```

use

```
String sql = String.format("INSERT INTO %s (%s) SELECT %s FROM %s",
  srcTableName, srcColumnsStr, dstColumnsStr, dstTableName);
```

**Or alternately and perhaps more correctly change the parameters when invoking the `copyTable` method so that :-**

- the first parameter is the name of the **timetables** table,
- the second parameter is the name of the **tmptimetables** table,
- the third parameter is the string array of the columns of the **timetables** table and
- the forth parameter is the string array of the columns of the **tmptimetables**.
- In short so that the insert becomes :-

  `INSERT INTO tmptimetables ( 
      _auto_complete, 
      _break_duration, 
      _color, 
      _first_lesson_time, 
      _first_week_date, 
      _id, 
      _lesson_duration,
      _symbol,
      _title, 
      _weeks
  ) 
  SELECT
      auto_complete, 
      break_duration, 
      color, 
      first_lesson_time, 
      first_week_date, 
      id, 
      lesson_duration, 
      symbol, 
      title, 
      weeks
   FROM timetables`

**Note** if the above is not the issue I'd suggest editing your question and including the actual data that is in the two tables. At a guess you are trying to insert using a specific id and that id already exists, which would contravene the `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` constraint

- PS `NOT NULL` is implied so there is no need to code `NOT NULL`,
- Additionally you may wish to read [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)  as there is a good chance that `AUTOINCREMENT` is detrimental as per *The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed.*

Comment: Thank you so much for detail answer but I think the problem can be due to `AUTOINCREMENT` only. I wanna check today.

Comment: @Шах `AUTOINCREMENT` won't be the problem, rather it could be `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`. This is what says (with or without AUTOINCREMENT) that the column is an alias of the special column **`rowid`** which will have a unqiue id (generally incrementing by 1) and that the column has a UNIQUE NOT NULL implied constraint. As it's UNIQUE you cannot insert, for example, with id = 1 if there is already a row with id  = 1 (as per note in asnwer).  What `AUTOINCREMENT` does is to guarantee a higher id, whilst without `AUTOINCREMENT`, a lower **`id`** can be applied.